# OpenSSL on android is "unable to get local issuer certificate" from sites that are trusted by other apps

Tags: android, openssl, libgit2

I have LibGit2 (v0.16.0-4936-g9c3e4e9) linked to a static build of the OpenSSL library  (v1.0.1f built with the help of [CMOSS](https://github.com/mevansam/cmoss)) running on Android (v4.3.1). During a clone from a github repository address `SSL_get_verify_result(ssl->ssl)` is called which results in a error with code 20, which is described in the OpenSSL docs as:

> 20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   the issuer certificate could not be found: this occurs if the issuer certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.

I have tried to manually set the path to the certification folder by calling

```
const char *android_cert_path = "/etc/security/cacerts/";
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(socket->ssl.ctx, NULL, android_cert_path);
```

Instead of the standard call by LibGit2 to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(socket->ssl.ctx)`But the error persists. When I visit github.com with Androids builtin browser it is said to be trusted so I guess the certificate of the issuer, in this case DigiCert, is somewhere in the phone. How should I make OpenSSL find the issuer certificate?

**Update**
I've confirmed that DigiCert is among the trusted credentials listed in `Settings > Security > Trusted Credentials`

Comment: @tomo - Does Android use `/etc/security/cacerts/`? Also, Github is certified by DigiCert. You only need to trust [`DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA`](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm). So why trust the entire the CA Zoo? If there are 150 certs in the `cacerts` file, then 149 are wrong for GitHub.

Comment: @jww - Yes, or the exact path was actually /system/etc/security/cacerts/ (/etc was a symlink to /system/etc), but changing it still doesn't help. From [wiki.cacerts.org](https://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/ImportRootCert#Android_Phones_.26_Tablets): _Starting from Android 4.0 (Android ICS/'Ice Cream Sandwich', Android 4.3 'Jelly Bean' & Android 4.4 'KitKat'), system trusted certificates are on the (read-only) system partition in the folder '/system/etc/security/' as individual files_ . I want my app to be compatible with other git-hosts as well that might be certified by other CAs.

Comment: When you say "other apps", do you mean other OpenSSL-using apps on Android or other apps in general? Have you looked at how they initialise OpenSSL?

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto I haven't found any example of an android app initiating OpenSSL in native code like C. For example the default android browser that I am refering to uses androids java-library under android.net.* to get SSL support. I think that most android apps uses OpenSSL in this way rather than in the lower-level way of Libgit2.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Dalvik/ART actually called out to OpenSSL instead of using their own crypto implementation. It's not so much about low vs high level, but being in java with its VM vs just having a barebones Linux system.